# Cannot delete a key value pair from js object

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, json, mongodb

I am receiving a js object from mongodb query and I want to remove a key value pair from object using delete optr but is not deleting and isFollowing value is not setting but the code in if part is running successfully. (using nodeJS)

I have already tried to delete using delete optr.... however it works with undefined but the value i am setting to isFollowing is not reflected in object.

```
baseData.numFollowers = baseData.followers.length;
    baseData.numFollowing = baseData.following.length;    
    if(forWhom === 'self'){
        delete baseData.following;
        delete baseData.followers;
    }else 
    if(forWhom === 'other'){
        const selfUID = req.body.self_id;
        baseData.isFollowing = baseData.followers.includes(selfUID);
        delete baseData.followers;
        delete baseData.following;

    }

    let toSend = {success:true, basic:baseData};
```

Getting result:

```
{ 
  following: [],
  followers: [],
  numFollowers: 0,
  numFollowing: 0
 }
```

Expected Result:

```
{
  numFollowers: 0,
  numFollowing: 0,
  isFollowing: true (or false)
}
```

Comment: This have to be something with mongoDB, not sure I'm not familar with it. Can you show your code how you save the data in DB?

Comment: @jcubic User.create(object).then((data)=>{}).catch((err)=>{});

Comment: Do you need to delete from the javascript simple object or from the database ?

Comment: @MoadEnnagi JS object. Did it with the help of first answer :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use `delete` you would need to convert the model document into a plain JavaScript object by calling `toObject` so that you can freely manipulate it like this:

```
const base = baseData.toObject();

base.numFollowers = base.followers.length;
    base.numFollowing = base.following.length;    
    if(forWhom === 'self'){
        delete base.following;
        delete base.followers;
    }else 
    if(forWhom === 'other'){
        const selfUID = req.body.self_id;
        base.isFollowing = base.followers.includes(selfUID);
        delete base.followers;
        delete base.following;

    }

    let toSend = {success:true, basic:base};
```